# Search and return in Excel VBA or Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for returning anything that is in Bin column as shown in the picture. Basically, in the first column, it may or may not contain some signals that are in Column B. I would like to return any signals in column B as a new column and ignore any signals that are not in Column B.
Any idea, what is the best way? Formula or VBA. Just to be clear, column 3 is what I want to output.
[Search and return signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlWVV.jpg)

Comment: You could do this using an array formula using `match` and `row`  Something like this, using E and F as columns `IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($F$1:$F$6,$E$1:$E$6,0))),ROW($E$1:$E$6))`  gives you an array of the row numbers where F is found in E

Comment: Could you specify your inputs and desired outputs? If a signal exists in column A and B you want it returned in column C, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks you guys for quick reply. Nathan, I am trying your method now, feedback to you in a bit. M. Schalk , my desire output will be the the same signal seen in both column A and B for each cell. Note that each cell have multiple signals.(see the pic for more details)

Comment: Hi Nathan, you formula seem to return row number, which is not what I am looking for. E,g, in the first cell, it contains signal (A, E,F), Database column B have (A,B,C D) four rows. The common signal is A, I would like signal A return in another column (should be same row number with (A,E,F). Thanks

Comment: @SamShang yes, it's not an answer, it's where to start.  Then you can use 'offset' maybe or something else to use the row numbers.

Comment: @Sam Shang: You may have to modify the first cell reference if your cells have extra spaces: TRIM(A1) ...  TRIM(B1)  -else it will have errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem to be interesting (and a bit challenging). Put this formula in the "Return" Column and copy down as needed. It will support up to seven characters in Column A.You can edit it manually if Column A exceeds this amount in the formula:

=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B1,A1,1)>0,B1,"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,1,1))>0,MID(A1,1,1),"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,2,1))>0,MID(A1,2,1),"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,3,1))>0,MID(A1,3,1),"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,4,1))>0,MID(A1,4,1),"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,5,1))>0,MID(A1,5,1),"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,6,1))>0,MID(A1,6,1),"")&IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,MID(A1,7,1))>0,MID(A1,7,1),""),"")